Unexpected Exception using Concurrent Futures
I am working on an evolutionary algorithm in Python. To speed things up, I am parallelizing the evaluation of the population using concurrent.futures and its class ProcessPoolExecutor.
The algorithm works for networks with up to 6 inputs. I tried to run it on networks with 8 inputs but an unexpected exception was generated.
Here you are the code I use to parallelize the evaluation:
    def select_best(self, population: list)
        start_time = time.time()
        ns = [self.inputs for _ in range(len(population))]
        # ----
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(cpus) as executor:
            fitness_list = list(executor.map(compute_fitness, population, ns))
        # ----
        individuals_and_fitness = sorted(
            zip(population, fitness_list), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        best_individuals = [individual for individual,
                            _ in individuals_and_fitness[:self.population_size]]
        best_fitness_scores = [
            fitness for _, fitness in individuals_and_fitness[:self.population_size]]

        self.fitness_history.append(best_fitness_scores[0])
        return best_individuals, best_fitness_scores

The compute_fitness function is this one:

def compute_fitness(individual, n=2):
    p = Phenotype(individual)
    nn = NNFromGraph(p, inputs=n, outputs=1)

    if nn.r == 0:
        return 0

    outputs = []
    targets = []

    # Generate all possible combinations of n binary inputs
    for combination in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n):
        input_data = torch.tensor(combination, dtype=torch.float32)

        # Get the output from the neural network
        output = nn(input_data)
        outputs.append(output.item())

        # Compute the expected parity of the input combination
        expected_parity = sum(combination) % 2
        targets.append(expected_parity)

    return normalized_mutual_info_score(outputs, targets)

After 640 generation (approx. 500 minutes), the following exception was thrown:
Exception in thread QueueManagerThread:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner

    self.run()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run

    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 394, in _queue_management_worker

    work_item.future.set_exception(bpe)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 547, in set_exception

    raise InvalidStateError('{}: {!r}'.format(self._state, self))

concurrent.futures._base.InvalidStateError: CANCELLED: <Future at 0x7fa9a464b3d0 state=cancelled>

Killed

I am running the code on a remote machine with 128 cores.
Another detail that may be important is that I noticed a weird behavior of the program: running the same code on my laptop (Mac Book Pro M3, 12 cores) or on the remote machine takes the same time for the evaluation, even if more than 10x cores can be used.
Using htop I can see that all cores are used for a short time, and then the execution goes back to the single core.
I also tried verifying that the bottleneck is indeed the evaluation and not the evolutionary algorithm. It is safe to say that the evaluation is almost 10x more time-consuming than the evolution.
Moreover, changing the fitness function with a dummy one that outputs random fitness values without evaluation seems to increase the time almost 4x.
Do you know how can I solve the problem?
Thank you in advance!

The error is, one process crashed or was terminated unexpectedly on your system, you need to handle this exception and act accordingly, like retry the iteration (though that may end up in an infinite loop of retry and failure if you don't find the actual reason for failure, like running out of memory)
